# Javascript calling Python not printing anything

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, sql

So my target was to pass the variables received from an HTML page to the python file and then call the python file at a stage and make it insert information into the SQL database. The python should only be run only if a certain function of javascript ends up in success. However, it seems that even know the python file is run in the network section, it does nothing despite having print statements at different points of the code.
Javascript:

```
if (otp.length == 6 && otp != null) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'controller.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : "json",
        data : input,
        success : function(response) {
            $("." + response.type).html(response.message)
            $("." + response.type).show();
                console.log(response);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "python.py",
                    data: { response},
                    dataType : "json",
                  }).done(function( response ) {
                      console.log('--response--', response)
                     // do something
                  });
        },
        error : function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            alert("Error encountered. Please try again later.");
        }
    });
}
```

Python code

```
print("Felicitations. La code marche")
import MySQLdb
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('add.html')

@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def getvalue():
    Gender=request.form['Gender']
    return Gender
    print(getvalue.Gender)

db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "name", "password", "fintech")
insertrec = db.cursor()
sqlquery= "INSERT INTO customers(Gender) VALUES('Gender')"
insertrec.execute(sqlquery)
db.commit()
print("Felicitations. La code marche")
db.close()
```

This is what shows up in the console/network:
[This information is not printed by python, but rather another php code so it's irrelevant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haA1x.png)

[The network shows that the python file is actually running, but it does not actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiW39.png)

Comment: A `return` ends the function. Nothing below it is executed.

Comment: @KlausD. do you mean the return Gender? In that case, why isn't the very first line of the python code being executed/printed?

Comment: They are on module level and should be printed when the server is starting up.

Comment: @KlausD. but the print statement in the first line is not on a module level. Also, "should be printed", but is not. That's why I am confused.

Comment: You don't seem to start the server. Also what does `url: "python.py"` mean? There's no such url binding in your server code. Do you expect that a python file will run when requested from a web server?

Comment: I used python.py because it's in the same folder as all other files in the server

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding on how to run a Flask application. If has to be started by a WSGI server. There is a simple one built into Flask. You can not simply run the file like a CGI script.